# Немного о черепахах и лексике

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, паронимы

Черепаховый суп из черепашьего мяса в черепашьем панцире, заказанный в кафе на черепаховой ферме?

Comment: В чём суть вопроса?

Answer (score 5):

**Черепаховый суп, черепаховая ферма** — здесь используется относительное прилагательное.

**Черепашье мясо, черепаший панцирь** — притяжательное прилагательное обозначает принадлежность черепахе (или применяется при сравнении с черепахой: черепаший ход, идти по-черепашьи).

Возможно колебание:

черепаший панцирь у черепахи и черепаховый панцирь как изделие из черепахи.

Черепаховое мясо, черепаший суп — неточное употребление прилагательных.